# Why is there now only one Salmonella species?

Tags: microbiology, history, bacteriology

Once upon a time, I chanced upon an old microbiology book that detailed the rather colorful world of enterobacteria. *Salmonella* in particular stood out, as it seemed there were a lot of species: *typhi* / *typhosa*, *paratyphi*, *gallinarum*, *typhimurium*, *choleraesuis*, and quite a bunch of others that I have now forgotten.

Flipping through a newer book, it now seems that all of these "species" were collated under *choleraesuis* (and now more recently *enterica*), with all those species being demoted to "strains" (or maybe I should use the current term of art, "serovar"). Unfortunately, the book didn't give much in the way of explaining about this merger.

So, why is there now only *S. enterica*? If "*S. typhi*" is a mere serovar, how come the species name is still used in the literature?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply put, old habits die hard; physicians and other medical personnel have grown up with the old species designations so will continue to use them.  This is somewhat the reverse of the case with *E. coli*, where [80-90% of the genome is variable](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2974192/?tool=pmcentrez) across strains.

[Lin-Hui gives a brief history](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17760271), where strains identified early were given specific names within *Salmonella* like *typhi*, *typhimurium*, *panama*, etc.  In 1966 it was proposed to lump serovars together among three species *S.
choleraesuis*, *S. typhosa*, and *S. kauffmannii*.  Shortly thereafter in 1972 with the advent of DNA techniques, it was shown they really should be all piled together.  There is one exception, *Salmonella choleraesuis subsp. bongori*, separated in 1989.

Comment: Nice survey article! (Even the switch from *choleraesuis* to *enterica* is discussed.) Thanks for this. I believe you intended "*typhosa*" instead of "*thphosa*", though.

Comment: @J.M. probably...it's misspelled in the review though `:/`

Answer (score 4):

Just open Wikipedia, your question is [answered there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salmonella#Salmonella_nomenclature):

> Initially, each Salmonella species was named according to clinical
>   considerations,[15] e.g., Salmonella typhi-murium (mouse typhoid
>   fever), S. cholerae-suis (hog cholera). After it was recognized that
>   host specificity did not exist for many species, new strains (or
>   serovar, short for serological variants) received species names
>   according to the location at which the new strain was isolated. Later,
>   molecular findings led to the hypothesis that Salmonella consisted of
>   only one species,[16] S. enterica, and the serovar were classified
>   into six groups,[17] two of which are medically relevant. But as this
>   now formalized nomenclature[18][19] is not in harmony with the
>   traditional usage familiar to specialists in microbiology and
>   infectologists, the traditional nomenclature is common. Currently,
>   there are two recognized species: S. enterica and S. bongori, with six
>   main subspecies: enterica (I), salamae (II), arizonae (IIIa),
>   diarizonae (IIIb), houtenae (IV), and indica (VI).[20] Historically,
>   serotype (V) was bongori, which is now considered its own species. The
>   serovar classification of Salmonella is based on the Kauffman-White
>   classification scheme that permits serological varieties to be
>   differentiated from each other. Newer methods for Salmonella typing
>   and subtyping include genome-based methods such as pulsed field gel
>   electrophoresis (PFGE), Multiple Loci VNTR Analysis (MLVA), Multilocus
>   sequence typing (MLST) and (multiplex-) PCR-based methods.[21]

Comment: Beautiful. Now, what were these "molecular findings" that were instrumental in collating all those *Salmonella* "species" (I don't have access to the journal article linked to)? And, why is "*S. typhi*" still used instead of "*S. enterica* serovar *typhi*"?